# is null with date() function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in in database in MySQL where 'uploadtime' is a column of datetime type. It may have null values. Furthermore, when I write the follwoing query:

```
SELECT uploadtime, date(uploadtime) FROM eidreport WHERE date(uploadtime) IS NULL
```

I get the following result:

```
+---------------------+------------------+
| uploadtime          | date(uploadtime) |
+---------------------+------------------+
| NULL                | NULL             |
| 2014-07-18 19:04:22 | 2014-07-18       |
| 2014-07-18 19:04:45 | 2014-07-18       |
| 2014-07-18 19:05:06 | 2014-07-18       |
| 2014-07-18 19:05:23 | 2014-07-18       |
| 2014-07-18 19:05:40 | 2014-07-18       |
| 2014-07-18 19:06:04 | 2014-07-18       |
```

and so on
The problem is: why are the dates listed in the second column ? I need the list of uploadtime values for which date(uploadtime) returns null. Just the condition "uploadtime IS NULL" won't work for me.

Comment: Weird issue. But I'm curious why *"Just the condition "uploadtime IS NULL" won't work for me."*

Comment: Can you please set up an SQL Fiddle so we can replicate and diagnose this issue?

Comment: Could not replicate - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd2db/5

Comment: Bulat Please send your email-id, I will provide you the sample dump

Comment: Shail, I don't have access to MySql other than sqlfiddle. You should be able to replicate it there, possibly you have other data type on your field.

Comment: Shail: Do replicate your issue on sqlfiddle, so you can have more people look into your issue.

Comment: It [works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/43269)